# PHP: Merge two array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, merge

Array 1:

```
array (size=1)
   0 => 
      object(stdClass)[93]
         public 'case' => string '12571' (length=5)
         public 'status' => string 'aktiv' (length=5)
         public 'id' => string '001345821' (length=9)
         public 'expires' => string '1392681600' (length=10)
```

Array 2:

```
array (size=66)
   0 => 
     object(stdClass)[25]
       public 'id' => string '001345821' (length=9)
       public 'date' => int 1415602800
       public 'amount' => string '1069.31' (length=7)
   1 => 
     object(stdClass)[26]
       public 'id' => string '001345680' (length=9)
       public 'date' => int 1415602800
       public 'amount' => string '1035.00' (length=7)
```

I want to merge array 1 and 2 on the "id" field and only keeping matches from array 1.

What i want:

```
array ()
   0 =>
     object(stdClass)
       public 'case' => string '1257' (length=5)
       public 'status' => string 'aktiv' (length=5)
       public 'id' => string '001345821' (length=9)
       public 'expires' => string '1392681600' (length=10)
       public 'date' => int 1415602800
       public 'amount' => string '1069.31' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object contains only properties, you could use array merge in this case. Of course, first up, just use a loop. Then under the loop, make your `if` checking for those who share the same ids then you need to cast them as array them merge, then recast them as object again:

```
foreach($array2 as &$value2) {
    foreach($array1 as $value1) {
        if($value2->id == $value1->id) {
            $value2 = (object) array_merge((array) $value2, (array) $value1);
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vV1e7m)